# Reading sequential user input to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, variables, input

I am very new to python, so apologise in advance if this question is straightforward.

I am writing a script in python that needs to ask the user for input sequentially (the input will all be floats), and then it needs to write that input to a list. The rest of the code will then do stuff with the list.

This is my first attempt:

```
num_array = list()

a1  = raw_input('Enter percentage of A (in decimal form): ')
a2 = raw_input('Enter percentage of B (in decimal form): ')
a3 = raw_input('Enter percentage of C (in decimal form): ')


li = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
for s in li:
num_array.append(float(s))
```

It all works except when we get down to reading the values into the array. Then I get the error:

```
 num_array.append(float(s))
 ValueError: invalid literal for float(): a1
```

I suspect that for a regular Python-coder the error is obvious, but this is literally the first time I'm using it :-) It's awesome, btw!

Any help would be much appreciated. As soon as it's running I will add things to deal with nonstandard inputs etc.

Comment: `li = [a1, a2, a3]` solves it (assuming your loop is actually properly indented)

Comment: That did it :-) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
li = [a1, a2, a3]
for s in li:
    num_array.append(float(s))
```

You want to refer to `a1` the variable and not `"a1"` the string

Note you could combine everything into your loop:

```
num_list = []
for c in ("A","B","C"):
    num_list.append(float(raw_input('Enter percentage of {} (in decimal form): '.format(c))))
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if `raw_input` is not a valid `float` though.

Comment: Thanks SO much, @Chris_Rands! What a great improvement :-D

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri `range` works fine of course, but I used this syntax to allow easy substitution of the alphabet letter strings into the loop

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that part that you are using that with `.format()`. Then it is fine. How about `for i in range(3): chr(65+i)` for more generic behavior?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri neat, but not suitable for the OP I think as it's their first ever python script. also bug if `chr(90)` exceeded (of course this can be worked around)

Comment: Awesome, @Chris_Rands! Just marked it as solved. Will upvote as soon as I have enough reputation...And thanks to @MoinuddinQuadri too...I will try and fix up the possible bugs as soon as I know more what I'm doing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str` type in `li` list, use the variables as:

```
 li = [a1, a2, a3]
```

Still your loop might raise `ValueError` if the value you are passing with `raw_input()` could not be convert into `float`. Better way to convert each item in `list` to `float` is:

via. *List Comprehension* as:

```
 num_list = [float(item) for item in [a1, a2, a3]]
```

OR, via `map()` as:

```
 num_list = map(float, [a1, a2, a3])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input ("enter the value of a")

b = input ("enter the value of b")

c = input {"enter the value of c")

l = [a,b,c]

num_array = []

for i in l:

    if type(i)==int
        i=float(i)
        num_array.append(i)
print l,num_array
```